# How to get highlighting for existing Arduino files in Sublime Text?

Tags: arduino, sublimetext3

I installed the package [Stino](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino), the screenshots on GitHub shows it enable syntax highlighting, and in fact if I open the examples from Arduino > Platform Examples, they indeed have syntax highlighting and autocompletion enabled, also if I created a new file and save it as INO.

The problem is, for my already written *.ino files, none of these works. Any solution on how to enable these for existing files? That doesn't involve manually copying and pasting the content of old files to new files (there's just too many).

Comment: If you meant that syntax highlighting doesn't show up for files that you had open at the time that you installed the package, closing and reopening the files in question would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

> View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as ...